# Create a vector from sampling based on 2 conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, simulation, sampling

I would like to to sample values from a vector `s<-0:1440` to create a vector `u` so that the `sum(u)=x` while `length(u)<k`, for given  `k`  and `x`. Obviously `k*max(s)>sum(u)`.

Is there any way to brute force simulate numerous such `u` vectors? I would like to avoid messing with probability distributions (for the sampling) and I don't care if some `u` vectors will get discarded.

**EDIT:** Regarding P Lapointe's nice comment about the `length(u)`. It is important that the `length(u)` should not be fixed (`length(u)<k`) so that the vectors `u` are of variable lengths. Another approach would be to fix the `length(u)=k`, but the algorithm should be able to randomly insert (simulate) zeros in the u vectors. This would have the consequence that by adding a zero, the `sum(u)` remains the same but the `length(u)` increases by one (until `length(u)=k`). It is important that the zeros appear randomly (not just at the end of the simulated vector, just to satisfy `length(u)=k`)

Comment: This seems like MIP (mixed integer programming) with a cardinality constraint (k). You can try the MIP solvers on http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: How many is "some"?  You could sample a very large number of vectors with fewer then `k` terms, and then discard all those which do not sum to `x`.

Comment: Could someone pin point me to some reading material for MIP (for beginners) to start with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here's an algo that answers your question. Basically, we are doing two random samples. The first one to find a k that satisfies the `length(u)<k` constraint. Using that k, we then use another sample to find `k-1` numbers. This is called `initial` in the algo. When we find a sample `k-1` which is lower than `x`, the desired sum, we add the difference of `x-sum(initial)` to complete the series.

```
#Inputs
x <-2500 # desired sum
s1<-0:min(1440,x) #universe
max.k <-10

k <-sample(3:(max.k-1),1) #length(u)<k, starts at 3 because low k can be problematic 
                          #with current inputs
initial <-x+1 #deliberately above limit to initialize the while
u <-s1+1      #deliberately above limit to initialize the while

while (sum(initial)>x | max(u)>max(s1)) {
initial <-sample(s1,k-1,replace=TRUE) #Find k-1 samples
u <-c(initial,x-sum(initial)) #add number that makes sum == x
}
 #example 
 > k
[1] 4
> x
[1] 2500
> u
[1]  282 1337  876    5
> sum(u)
[1] 2500
```

Also, if you have a large `max.k`, it might be a good thing to add a probability vector that gives more probability to low numbers in the sample. Otherwise, in the current example, it is tough to get a sum==2500 if you have several numbers above 1000.

```
prob1 <-1/((s1+1)*max.k ) #gives more probality to low numbers

while (sum(initial)>x | max(u)>max(s1)) {
initial <-sample(s1,k-1,replace=TRUE,prob=prob1) #Find k-1 samples
u <-c(initial,x-sum(initial)) #add number that makes sum == x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can brute force the `length(u)<k` constraint without a MIP. But if you fix it to a number, you can use `sample`.

In this example, the first five lines are samples, the sum is added on the last line of the matrix. You can increase the size of the `replicate` (currently at 20000) if you do not find a match. You should also check `range(all[k+1,])` to see if you desired sum (`x`) is within sampled sums.

```
set.seed(1)
s<-0:1440 #universe
k <-5 #fixed number of items in sample
x <-2500 # desired sum
all <-replicate(20000, sample(s,k,replace=TRUE))
all <-rbind(all,colSums(all))
all[,all[k+1,]==x,drop=FALSE] #gives two possible samples

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]  410  241
[2,]  189  687
[3,]  988  401
[4,]  897  983
[5,]   16  188
[6,] 2500 2500
```

Comment: I see your point but this is painfully slow. It is *very* important that length(u) is not fixed. Another approach would be to fix the length(u)  but the algorithm could random insert (simulate) zero's to the u (which  would have the consequence that by adding a 0 to the u, the sum would remain the same but the length would increase).